# How to find most frequent string in List of strings

Tags: scala

I have a list of strings (`List[String]`) and I want to obtain the most frequent string from this list:

```
val list1 = List('a','a','0','b','b','a')
```

The answer should be:

```
freq_list1 = a
```

I was thinking to use `list1.sliding(2).count...` in order to get the count of unique string, but I don't know how to wrap it into finding the most frequent string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list1.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)._1
```

EDIT: See comment below, can be made shorter by using `maxBy(_._2.size)` without mapping beforehand, thanks @kawty

Comment: `list1.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1` is shorter